# Casting redundant or not

Tags: c#, casting

Here is my original function

```
 private static Int32 getInt(byte[] Data, char Endianness)
        {
            if (Data.Length > 3)
            {
                switch (Endianness)
                {
                    case 'l':
                        return ((Int32)(Data[3]) << 24) + ((Int32)(Data[2]) << 16) + ((Int32)(Data[1]) << 8) + (Int32)(Data[0]);
                    case 'b':
                        return ((Int32)(Data[0]) << 24) + ((Int32)(Data[1]) << 16) + ((Int32)(Data[2]) << 8) + (Int32)(Data[3]);
                    default:
                        throw new ArgumentException("Wrong endianness type", "Endianness types are 'l' or 'b'");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("NVM data corruption", "Failed to parse NVM data");
            }
        }
```

I am using Resharper and it suggested I remove the casting to Int32 since it is redundant.

so we get this code as an output

```
 private static int getInt(byte[] Data, char Endianness)
    {
        if (Data.Length > 3)
        {
            switch (Endianness)
            {
                case 'l':
                    return (Data[3] << 24) + (Data[2] << 16) + (Data[1] << 8) + Data[0];
                case 'b':
                    return (Data[0] << 24) + (Data[1] << 16) + (Data[2] << 8) + Data[3];
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Wrong endianness type", "Endianness types are 'l' or 'b'");
            }
        }
        throw new ArgumentException("NVM data corruption", "Failed to parse NVM data");
    }
```

in the code you have see I am shifting `Data[2] << 16` that number can overflow from the original byte, if I removed the cast to Int32 am I risking here some  sort of trim to byte?

Can you please explain what C# preprocessor/ compiler is doing here?

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the `<<` operator, you see that it returns an `int32` and not an `int16` so yes, it's redundant. just hover your mouse over it

Comment: @sLw I can't see what you are describing

Comment: hover your mouse over the `<<` operator and you will see that it returns an `int` (32bit) -> `Data[2] << 16` <- this operator returns an `int`

Comment: @sLw I am, but I can't see it, I am using VS2013 Update 5, maybe that's why?

Comment: @sLw I think this feature appears in VS2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is redundant because compiler automatically promotes `Data[2]` to integer when you use `left-shift` operator and the result of that operation will also be an integer. So no data will be lost.